# Dojo Framework: CrossFrame Approach?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm looking for a dojo toolkit approach to communicating across iFrames. Something similar to Julien Lecomte's CrossFrame technique shown here http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/11/31/. His approach uses a YUI library function. Is there anything of the sort in Dojo?

I checked out dojo.io.frame, but that doesn't seem to be able to communicate from one frame to another frame on the same page... it just allows you to post/request data to a 3rd party server.

I'm looking to communicate *between* a 3rd party Iframes and its host document. Ie:

iFrameA (mydomain.com/iframea) is embedded in webpageB (anotherdomain.com/webpageB).

I want a function in iFrameA to be able to securely call a function in webpageB. Presumably via a proxy on anotherdomain.com.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Kris Zyp's `dojox.io.windowName` which gives you a low-level ability to pass strings.  You may also want to look at the [Open Ajax Hub 2.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openajaxallianc/) which has a pluggable framework for cross-frame communication and uses a pub/sub model.  It also uses embedded iframes. I'm not sure how it differs from CrossFrame.